# Capture Pasted Input in Javascript

Tags: jquery, regex

Hello I want to capture some input and test to see if its a url in order to shorten it or discredit from the character count similar to twitter.
I have a function already that sets the character count on a paste event but I do not now how to grab what was pasted

```
    var urlexp = new RegExp( '/(\b(https?):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig' );
    var message = $("#post-msg").text();
    var twstartchars = 140 - message.length;
    var fbstartchars = 420 - message.length;
    $("#post-msg").bind("input paste", function (e) {
                    var a=$("#post-msg").val().length;
                    var post = $("post-msg").val();

                    if ( urlexp.test(post) ){
                            $('.shortenlinks').show();
                    }

                    $("#fb-char").text((420-a));
                    $("#tw-char").text((140-a));
                    if ( a > 120 ){
                            $("#tw-char").css('color','red');
                            if ( a > 380 ){
                                    $("#fb-char").css('color','red');
                            }
                    }else{
                            $("#fb-char").css('color','#333');
                            $("#tw-char").css('color','#333');
                    }

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need to debug your code first :)

Your URL regex is not working for me. Try it yourself by adding

```
alert(urlexp.test("http://google.com"));
```

somewhere. Returns false for me, so i replaced it with another random URL regex:

```
urlexp = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/g
```

This one is working for me.

Second point is there is the # hash sign missing in the selector:

```
var post = $("post-msg").val();
```

Should be

```
var post = $("#post-msg").val();
```

To grab what was pasted, just read the #post-msg value, as you are doing already. Apply the URL regex to the string and extract the URLs from it:

```
$(".shortenlinks").innerHtml(""); // clear links
while(var match = urlexp.exec($("#post-msg").val())) {
    $(".shortenlinks").append(match[0] + "<br />"); // add each link
}
```